# Python regular expression to find the pattern exists in the given string

Tags: python, regex

I am working on Fancy mobile number list using python re. what is the pattern for getting the incremental digits in between the 10 digit mobile number
    pattern for mobile number `xxxxxx1234, xxxxx12345, xxxx123456` etc using python re

Comment: use a simple iteration over string and keep track of last value, if the delta between current value last value is one ( -ve  or +ve depends how you're subtracting ), than it's a incremental number, and keep track of max length of such to get pattern with most incremental number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?")
pattern.search("12343445")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1234'>
```

I think this works

Comment: Can i get the pattern for this 1462111462 , i tries with re.match("\d(\d{3})\1(\d)\2{2}(\d{3}\1$',1462111462') , but not working

Comment: I got 146 for the result. Isn't is correct?

Comment: 462 should repeat 2 times and in between 3 same digits

Comment: It's not incremental value. But if you want, you can use pattern = re.compile("\d+"). I don't think I'm exactly understanding what you want to say though.

Comment: sorry this is a sepearte match . i want to find a pattern in the above number 1 462 111 462 like ? ABC XXX ABC

Comment: re.compile(r"\d?(\d{3})([0-9])\2{2}\1") this worked totally fine for me.

Comment: Its working thanks

Comment: could be please help for the pattern (ABABAAAXYZ) example is 4343555123

Comment: This getting too far from the beginning. Please post another question and I'll answer it.

Comment: ok thanks i got from your previous post